# How do I programmatically login or get the JWT token of a logged in Google user in Azure AD?

Tags: azure, active-directory, google-authentication

I already setup the Google Identity Provider in Azure Active Directory and can invite users to my application. After the Google user accepts the invitation, I can see their user object in Active Directory. What I would like to do next is to programmatically login the user using the Google federation or get the JWT token of the logged in Google user.

For user objects created in AD, I can programmatically login the users using ROPC. I understand this is not possible for external users authenticated using Google federation.

Answer (score 0):

•   Kindly please take note of this that Azure AD does not support ROPC flow method of credential authentication for federated accounts. Also, when you are using ROPC method, your credentials are at risk of compromise as they are passed directly in the body of API authentication request. Thus, I would suggest you use client credential flow for this purpose as it can access the data from both sides.

•   Since you want to programmatically login using the Google federated user to some application or SaaS platform, I would suggest you refer the below link which describes sufficiently how you can use the federated domain’s user login credentials to login to an application or a SaaS platform. In this link, it is stated that you should configure the Azure Policy regarding the Home realm discovery to false and configure the federated domain as its preferred domain for logging in. Also, if you want to retrieve the access token only, then you can use the ‘Postman’ application or ‘https://jwt.ms’ as the redirect URI for that purpose.

https://medium.com/@amanmcse/ropc-username-password-flow-fails-with-aadsts50126-invalid-username-or-password-for-federated-90c666b4808d